# how to set config file for WSGIPassAuthorization On for token authentication in django with apache

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am hosting a ubuntu server for django application with djangorestframework with apache webserver. I have a problem with token authentication. All api's works fine on localhost but not works on the server. This response has come when calling to the server.

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Some one told me to change its config file and add this line to config file because apache uses its own token authentication as default.

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

So i have added this line to my config file and after that same response is coming. kindly tell me what to do next?

**views.py**

```
class ManageUserView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer for the users object """

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password', 'user_type')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 8}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Create a new user with encrypted password and return it"""
        print(validated_data)
        return get_user_model().objects.create_type_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """ Update a user, setting the password correctly and return it """
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return user
```

**site.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.shabber.tech
    ServerAdmin official.kisaziaraat@gmail.com
    ServerAlias shabber.tech
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /home/shabber/apna/static
    <Directory /home/shabber/apna/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/shabber/apna/media
    <Directory /home/shabber/apna/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/shabber/apna/apna>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/shabber/apna/apna/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess apna_app python-path=/home/shabber/apna python-home=/home/shabber/apna/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup apna_app
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```